# What is the biblical basis for the belief that good works are the fruits of faith?

Tags: biblical-basis, protestantism, faith, works

It is common for Protestant doctrinal statements to say that good works are the fruits of faith. For example:

> We confess that *good works are necessary fruits of faith* in the life of a Christian and that they proceed from a renewed heart that is thankful to God for His mercy and love. Although there is no human cooperation in the matter of one’s conversion and justification, there is a cooperation on the part of the regenerate Christian in his or her life of sanctification. Good works do not earn or contribute to one’s salvation, *but they naturally flow from the living faith* which is present in the hearts of those who have already been saved by God’s grace alone. ("[We Believe, Teach and Confess](http://els.org/beliefs/we-believe-teach-and-confess/)," Evangelical Lutheran Synod, italics added)

And:

> Although *good works, which are the fruits of faith,* and follow after justification, cannot put away our sins, and endure the severity of God's judgment; yet are they pleasing and acceptable to God in Christ, and *spring out of a true and lively faith,* insomuch that by them a lively faith may be as evidently known as a tree is discerned by its fruit. ([The Articles of Religion of the Methodist Church](http://www.umc.org/what-we-believe/the-articles-of-religion-of-the-methodist-church), italics added)

What is the biblical basis for the belief that good works are the fruits of faith?

Please note that I am *not* asking whether good works are necessary for salvation, whether people of faith should do good works, and so on. Nor am I asking for the biblical basis of good works being a result of being saved, flowing from Christ, and so on.

I am asking specifically for the biblical basis of the belief that good works are the fruits of *faith,* the result of *faith,* flow from *faith,* and similar formulations.

Does the Bible anywhere state this clearly? If not, what Bible passages are quoted by Protestant churches and major Protestant theologians to support this belief, and how do they interpret those passages to support it?

Comment: Please clarify or distinguish faith from salvation.  Perhaps just a simple working definition?  Salvation without faith is not really salvation or certainly not a commonly accepted definition of either.

Comment: @nickalh For the purposes of this question, I don't think it's necessary to define salvation, because the question is *not* whether good works flow from salvation. If an *answerer* wants to define salvation as part of the answer, that's fine, as long as the answer actually answers the question asked.

Comment: How can something like "Although there is no human cooperation in the matter of one’s conversion and justification," be said when Jesus specifically tells people to "repent" etc?

Comment: @SolaGratia Though I would be happy to have that conversation with you, the comments here aren't the place to discuss doctrines and beliefs. For that we have [The Upper Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/the-upper-room) chatroom.

Comment: Cool. I wasn't aware of such a cyber-abode. I may pop in some time, hopefully I'll find you around. As for now, I can't get into a chat quite *now*. Meanwhile, God bless.

Answer (score 4):

> I am asking specifically for the biblical basis of the belief that
>   good works are the fruits of faith.

[Hebrews 11](https://www.blueletterbible.org/esv/heb/11/1/s_1144001) addresses this directly.

Verse 6 is instructive, for it tells us that without faith it is impossible to please God. The rest of the chapter goes on to tell us how the ancients expressed their faith. Their works were the fruits -- the outflow, the results -- of their faith. Another way to put it is that these men and women would not have acted the way they had if they did not have faith in God and what He said to them.

Noah heard God tell him about the ark and the coming judgment. He believed God, so he built it.

Moses heard God tell him about leading the exodus. He believed God, so he obeyed and led the Israelites out.

Abraham believed God and showed it by following through on what was said of him. Throughout the chapter, we see that faith motivated them to act.

If faith means "to believe without proof," then these passages don't make any sense. When you apply the biblical definition to the verses -- having a firm conviction that something is so -- then all the verses give light. This is how you know someone has a firm conviction of God's word -- she follows through on the words.

The biblical idea of faith in these verses indicate that if you really believe that what you heard or read comes from God, then you will act on what you believe. There are no armchair Christians pleasing God. As James 2:36 says, "Faith without works is dead." The faith of those in Hebrews 11 was not dead.

Note that in Galatians, the works of faith are being distinguished from ongoing religious rituals, forms, rules, and laws. The “faith that works through love” (Galatians 5:6) is a faith that responds in obedience to what God has said, and the works reflect love for the individual being helped, or one’s love for God, not routine forms of conduct. Read the works of Hebrews 11 and the works of the apostles in Acts and you won’t find faith showing itself as adherence to sets of religious rules and laws, but as obedience to God and love for neighbor.

Comment: This is lost on a lot of modern people, the context of what faith represents.  *When you apply the biblical definition to the verses -- having a firm conviction that something is so -- then all the verses give light.*  +1

Comment: Just for the record,the Catholic faith has never taught good works are meritorious—meaningful, beneficial, pleasing to God—before conversion to faith in Christ and being a justified believer. It powerfully teaches that *faith precedes works.* Something lost on a lot of Protestants.

But to say faith *itself* **produces** good works, rather than that inthe *faithful* servant of God the Spirit of God imparts the grace to do good works, is an odd thing to say.

Comment: Beautifully said brother. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

When answering some questions of a biblical nature, the questioner needs to harmonize, so to speak, a number of scriptures, much in the way readers of the four Gospels (yes, including John's Gospel) might harmonize an event in the life of Christ.

So it is with your question. Since searching for a "proof text" is likely not your MO, we need to look for a number of texts which together make a teaching clear, which in your case is the teaching that good works, or fruits, in the life of believers flow from faith. I believe they do.

First, the apostle Paul makes one thing perfectly clear:

> . . . and whatever is not from faith is sin (Romans 14:23b NASB).

The verse, of course, is within the context of a chapter concerning "Principles of Conscience" (as the NASB puts it). In the chapter, Paul differentiates between two types of Christians: First, is the brother (or sister) who is "weak in faith," which is not necessarily a description of the person's Christian life in general but the person's Christian life specifically regarding what could be called "grey issues."

In Paul's day, a divisive grey issue involved the eating of meat which had been sacrificed to idols. Some believers did not have faith that eating this meat was God's will for them; consequently, they refrained from doing so. Some other believers, like Paul himself, did not have a scruple about eating this meat, since he and they knew--or had the faith that

> . . . nothing in unclean in itself (14:14a).

He goes on to say in the same verse, however, that

> . . . but to him who thinks anything to be unclean, to him it *is* unclean (v.14b, my emphasis).

Just to be clear, thinking something is or is not clean is a matter of faith (again, see 14:1). A Christian who by faith refuses to eat meat sacrificed to idols is approved by God, as is the Christian who by faith partakes of meat sacrificed to idols is approved by God. Both actions are in the category of "good deeds" or "good works," but both are expressed in different ways.

Parenthetically, a Christian "ministry" in the area of, say, teaching or preaching the Word, is also expressed in different ways from person to person. [Actually, the same could be said of virtually any one of the "spirituals," and I say "spirituals" since most Bible versions insert the word *gifts* after the word *spiritual*, so we often refer to the "spirituals" as "spiritual gifts." In my opinion there is nothing wrong with this.]

Some believers might have a niche in teaching youngsters, or teens, or college-and-career folks, or adults with a variety of SMQs (spiritual maturity quotients). The teacher, himself or herself, is still a gift to the church (as is the apostle, prophet, and evangelist--Ephesians 4), and God expects his or her teaching to proceed from faith and to be exercised in the strength which only God can supply (1 Peter 4:11).

Second, if good deeds which do not proceed from faith are tantamount to sin (again, Romans 14:23b), then the faithless Christian is not bearing the kind of fruit which God desires for him or her and is not truly bearing fruit. To bear fruit consistently and in a manner which passes God's muster, or judgment (Romans 12:10-12 ff.), a believer must be acting in faith.

This action in faith applies not just to matters of conscience or scruples; rather, it applies to every aspect of fruit bearing. Abiding by faith in Christ the true vine is the only way to bear fruit which remains and will be judged acceptable by God (John 15:1-17, especially vv.5-8). The word faith may not be used in John Chapter 15, but it is certainly a fundamental aspect of fruit bearing.

The biblical teaching on fruit bearing and its relationship to matters of faith, then, is a concatenation of at least two (and quite likely more than two) teachings; namely, works which proceed from faith are not sin, and those works are fruits which bring glory to God, stimulate spiritual growth, and will be rewarded by God.

In conclusion, Christians who are maturing in their Christian walk and in their sanctification are exercising their faith in ways which bear much fruit, and by doing so are approved by God and rewarded handsomely in  this life, as well as in the life to come (see Romans 14:10-12 and 2 Corinthians 5:6-10, where in the former reference Paul says, "for we walk by faith, not by sight," and we "will be recompensed [at the judgment seat of Christ] for [our] deeds in the body, according to what [we] have done, whether good or bad").

Comment: "rewarded handsomely in this life"  this is a curious statement.  In what way?

Comment: The rewards I'm alluding to are, for example, 1) knowing that I'm progressing in the faith, kind of like the athlete who has broken his personal best time in some athletic event; 2) seeing other people being blessed by my ministry, whether it's a ministry of teaching, helping, exhorting, admonishing, evangelizing, giving, leading,  administrating, or any other kind of fruit bearing; 3) feeling the God's hand on my life--his encouragement, blessing; 4) knowing that I'm doing my part in "working out my own salvation" so that God can then provide the willing and the doing. Those are just four.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good argument, based on biblical texts, for the idea that *good works flow from faith*:

1. The law (i.e. good works defined by God) is fulfilled through *love*.
2. Love is a fruit of faith.

Some biblical support for these two points:

## Love satisfies God's law

i.e. good works are done by "love".

> Owe no one anything, except to love each other, for the one who loves another has fulfilled the law. For the commandments, “You shall not commit adultery, You shall not murder, You shall not steal, You shall not covet,” and any other commandment, are summed up in this word: “You shall love your neighbor as yourself.” Love does no wrong to a neighbor; therefore love is the fulfilling of the law.-- Romans 13:8-10 (ESV)
>
> For the whole law is fulfilled in one word: “You shall love your neighbor as yourself.” -- Galatians 5:14 (ESV)
>
> So whatever you wish that others would do to you, do also to them, for this is the Law and the Prophets. -- Matthew 7:12 (ESV)
>
> If you really fulfill the royal law according to scripture, "You shall love your neighbor as yourself," you do well -- James 2:8 (ESV)

So following the law, or doing good works, is composed of *loving* others.

## Love issues from faith

i.e. love flows from, is produced by, is a fruit of faith.

> Beloved, let us love one another, *for love is from God*, and whoever loves has been born of God and knows God. -- 1 John 4:7 (ESV)
>
> For in Christ Jesus neither circumcision nor uncircumcision counts for anything, but only faith working through love. -- Galatians 5:6 (ESV)
>
> But the fruit of the Spirit is love, joy, peace, patience, kindness, goodness, faithfulness, -- Galatians 5:22
>
> Let me ask you only this: Did you receive the Spirit by works of the law or by hearing with faith? Are you so foolish? Having begun by the Spirit, are you now being perfected by the flesh? -- Galatians 3:2-3 (ESV)

---

I think those two points are enough to answer your questions. This is certainly not a comprehensive argument of all biblical arguments for this, but it does provide some examples.

(note: I was introduced to this argument through [this resource](http://www.desiringgod.org/messages/why-the-law-was-given). He goes on to conclude that even the Mosaic law was intended to be fulfilled by faith, not works)

---

A few other scriptures indicating that faith is necessary for good works:

> For whatever does not proceed from faith is sin. -- Romans 14:23

Hebrews 11, as another answer details also points us towards this conclusion.

Most of the book of Galatians was written to address similar questions. Although most of that book is about salvation through faith, which as you've said is a slightly different question. However, reading straight through Galatians should probably help to see some of the foundation of this idea as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to be clear, my personal belief is that "good works are the fruits of faith" is mistaken. Instead, I believe that good works are the fruit of *God,* and of God's *love* working in us, and that faith is the *conduit* through which that love produces fruit.  However, having frequently heard the statement from Protestants that "good works are the fruits of faith," I was curious where they get it from. And the answers so far confirm for me that the Bible does not actually say this, but that it is the result of reading the Bible through the lens of Protestant doctrine.

Comment: "Good works are the fruit of God, and of God's love working in us". Ya, I definitely agree with that! I think most protestants do as well.

"faith is the conduit through which that love produces fruit".  I think this is mixing metaphors.. I think I get what you're saying - that it's God who produces the fruit not simply our faith. I think most Christians who say "good works are the fruit of faith" would agree 100% with that. Phrasing it as "the fruit of faith" just helps to show that we have faith in God's work in us to produce good works, rather than just working on our own.

Answer (score 0):

> OP: What is the biblical basis for the belief that good works are the fruits of faith?

To clarify, first comes grace from God through faith not of yourself but as a gift (Eph 2:8), then from that faith may come good works.  Where is that in the Bible?  Is it an invention of the Reformation or has it existed some 2,000 years?

The answer is found a couple verses later and elsewhere.

> For we are his workmanship, created in Christ Jesus unto good works, which God hath before ordained that we should walk in them. Eph. 2:10.

In other words, we are saved by grace through faith for what reason?  For good works.  Whose?  God's prepared works for us, even prior to our salvation.

Good works is the fruit.  Paul to Titus contrasts unfruitful with good works.

> And let ours also learn to maintain good works for necessary uses, that they be not unfruitful. Titus 3:14

Peter outlines the same thought that faith may result in good works.

> And beside this, giving all diligence, add to your **faith** virtue; and to virtue knowledge; And to knowledge temperance; and to temperance patience; and to patience godliness; And to godliness brotherly kindness; and to brotherly kindness charity.
> For if these things be in you, and abound, they make you that ye shall neither be barren nor **unfruitful** in the knowledge of our Lord Jesus Christ. 2 Peter 1:5-8 emphasis mine

So, the belief that good works are the fruit of faith is Biblical.

Answer (score 0):

## James Chapter 2

There are good answers here, and I know that this post is old, but I feel that there should be more emphasis here on the teachings from James 2:14-26 because, as I understand it, this is the central passage showing specifically what is being asked in this question, that faith *causes* good works. Reading the quotes you placed, I suspect that they were most heavily inspired by this passage.

### The general message of James

I believe that the passage itself would be a familiar one to most Christians, but to put it into perspective, first consider the book and how it is taught. I have heard the specific book referred to in a group of books known to some Protestants as the "Reality Epistles", including, for instance, the general epistles of Peter and John. The purpose of these Epistles is to help the audience to determine whether their salvation is genuine. Even more so than the others, the general aim of the Epistle of James is to show that the ways that we live our daily life are reflective of whether or not the things we say or want to believe about ourselves is in fact in harmony with reality. Throughout the book James uses many examples, including the way that we pray, the ways that we talk, and how we treat other people. In all of these other areas, James isn't trying to just show us that we should try to do better, but specifically that we can see with hard proof that what we say is not true. If we pray and don't accept God's answer, we're not really praying. If we judge people by their status, we don't really believe that all people are equal before God. He gives a clear picture for the tongue:

> James 3:12 - Can the fig tree, my brethren, bear olive berries? either a vine, figs? so can no fountain both yield salt water and fresh.

If we hurt people with our words, it's not that we didn't hold our tongue, but that we aren't really clean inside our heart. We can't just try to say better things and be okay any more than a fig tree just work harder at bearing olives. Either you are a new creature or you are not.

### James 2 within that context

So, can this type of thought be applied to the end of chapter 2 as Protestants teach? The most clear verse is 2:18:

> Yea, a man may say, Thou hast faith, and I have works: shew me thy faith without thy works, and I will shew thee my faith by my works.

Note that the man without works can only "say" that he has faith. However, if one has faith, that fact can be shown by his works. The Greek word we translate faith is "πίστις", from "πείθω" meaning "to be persuaded". Faith is never given in the Greek as being simply a mental creed or statement which simply checks off or agrees to something, but it is something of which you are actually persuaded. If I said that I believed the building is on fire and didn't leave, the problem isn't that I was just lazy but that I wasn't actually persuaded that it was true. We always act on what we actually believe.

What are the "good works" of James 2? He doesn't have to say them explicitly because they are simply the "works" spelled out in the rest of the book. They are things such as rejoicing when trouble comes, praying to God sincerely, not mistaking God as a tempter, obeying the Bible, don't treat certain people differently, don't speak hurtful, negative things, don't be proud, etc. These are all things that, if we truly are persuaded of the truth of Christ and the Bible, we would simply be doing. If we are not doing them, the problem isn't that we're lazy, but that we aren't truly persuaded.

Note the verses 21 and 22:

> James 2:21-22 (emphasis mine): Was not Abraham our father justified by works, when he had offered Isaac his son upon the altar? **Seest thou how faith wrought with his works**, and by works was faith made perfect?

James must clearly be pointing out an integral connection between faith and works, such that if works didn't happen, then the faith would either not exist in truth or the faith would have no effect. If you were to read James by itself, and you failed to catch the rest of the context from the book, you might be tempted to accept the later, that James might be talking about there being a faith that could exist which could be both real and would have no benefit. However, that concept would not be available for most Protestants as they believe that all Scripture is equally as authoritative and in harmony with each other, and so they would be forced to consider the works of Paul.

### Compared with the writings of Paul

Much of the writings of Paul deal with the same topic, that salvation is not simply a creed or birthright, but instead it is a wholly new nature, and one which has some tangible differences from the old nature, using the term "born again". I would expect that every Protestant is familiar with Ephesians 2:8-10 (emphasis mine):

> For by grace are ye **saved through faith**; and that not of yourselves: it is the gift of God: **Not of works**, lest any man should boast. For we are his workmanship, created in Christ Jesus **unto good works**, which God hath before ordained that we should walk in them.

Paul is very clear that works is not any part of salvation, but faith is. Works are something that happen after salvation. Therefore, if both passages are equally true and speaking of the same salvation, one which occurs by faith without any works being a part of it, and if faith without works is useless, then I think the only natural understanding of the text of James is that faith which does not produce works is not actually faith at all, just as a fig tree is not an olive tree at all, regardless of how many olives are on it or not at a given moment. Nevertheless, if it were an olive tree, then the only fruit to grow on it, in time, would be olives.

### The Protestant perspective

The Protestant perspective is that what people do is reflective of what they believe. Protestants doctrine teaches that salvation is something that is done by God and for God, in spite of the sinfulness of the men He saves, and that this change is something which is not simply a matter of doctrinal agreement, church membership, or recognition by some other human, but it is a real change of a person's nature, and that change involves faith, which is actually being persuaded of the truth of Jesus' teachings and the Bible. Hebrews chapter 11 is called "The Hall of Faith" and in all the teachings about faith, it is all records of people who believed what God said and who acted as if it were true even though it did not make any sense, and even though the reward was not in this life. It shouldn't be hard to see how anybody so persuaded, who believes that the Bible is authoritative and consistent, would see passages such as James 2:14-26 as clearly stating the causal nature of faith to works.

Answer (score -1):

***What is the biblical basis for the belief that good works are the fruits of faith?***

**This belief is directly based on the parables of Jesus**....and is understood deeply by those with ears to hear. Its truth that can be arrived at by anyone with a pure heart whose intention is true.

**The majority of Jesus' parables explaining his Kingdom use the analogy of a Farmer cultivating the earth.**

When one who is blessed with life on the earth, looks objectively like a babe on the magnificence and intelligence inherent wihin the design.... a deeper nature of the 1 Creator, YHWH becomes evident. A nature of an Eternal Father sowing seed.

One of the Fundamental Truths evident in the observation of His creation is that ***seeds make more seeds***. Life will not propagate without this law He has built in. It allows Him to keep this organic system on autopilot for as much as He desires.

At this time, God is working to renew the corrupted spirit seeds of His genesis creation lineage. The way He has presented us is perfect. He presented a New Seed by begetting Jesus.  Now God our Father and Farmer is watering the Vine of the New Seed with His holy Spirit. In this way, the old corrupted seeds (you and I) can be renewed incorruptible and brought back into the fold becoming Branches on the True Vine.  As branches we produce ***Fruit*** which bring **more seeds**.

*God's intention is for humankind to cultivate and produce from the earth.*  A Farmer sows **seed** in the springtime.  ***Faith*** is the life of the farmer for he/she must put their complete livelihood in the hands of Thee Farmer, our Father - the 1 eternal Seed.

No good works can be done apart from this new Vine.
In this way, "Good works are the fruits of faith" - For only by faith can we hope to be a chosen branch on the 1 Vine of the New Creation.

John 15

> ***The True Vine***

> 15 ***“I am the true vine, and My Father is the Farmer***. 2 Every **branch** in Me that does not bear **fruit** He takes away; and every branch that bears **fruit** He prunes, that it may bear more **fruit.** 3 You are already clean because of the word which I have spoken to you. 4 Abide in Me, and I in you. **As the branch cannot bear fruit of itself, unless it abides in the vine, neither can you, unless you abide in Me.**

> 5 “I am the **vine**, you are the **branches**. He who abides in Me, and I in him, bears much ***fruit***; for without Me you can do nothing. 6 If anyone does not abide in Me, he is cast out as a branch and is withered; and they gather them and throw them into the fire, and they are burned. 7 If you abide in Me, and My words abide in you, you[b] will ask what you desire, and it shall be done for you. 8 By this My Father is glorified, that you bear much ***fruit; so you will be My disciples.***